# Search QString in QComboBox

Tags: c++, search, qt4, qstring, qcombobox

How can I find a QString in a QComboBox? I want to get the index of the element in the combobox that's corresponding to my string. Is there a native method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Qt documentation is really well done. I would start there for any questions like this that you have in the future. Most methods are reasonably named in a descriptive manner. A few that caught me off guard is the use of `take` like in `takeTopLevelItem` within a `QTreeWidget` instead of `remove`.

Comment: You are right. I must learn how to use online documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the [findText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#findText) method is what you're looking for